# Is it possible to use an SVG Sprite map in Storybook react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, storybook

I have a react build that has a `npm run dev` tast and a `npm run storybook`. My dev task uses the index.ts as you would expect, however storybook (my the looks of things) bundles up packages for each story found.

My problem is that my entry file uses SVG go to create and import a sprite map of SVGs that are in a specific folder

```
import './styles/main.scss';
import './App';
import svgxhr from '../node_modules/webpack-svgstore-plugin/src/helpers/svgxhr';


const __svg__ = {
  path: './media/img/svg/*.svg',
  name: 'sprite-store.svg',
};

svgxhr(__svg__);
```

So when i view my components that reference my svgs like so...

```
 <svg>
   <title>{title}</title>
   <use xlinkHref={reference}></use>
 </svg>
```

It displays them but only when using the `npm run dev` task because thats where is gets imported.

Is there anyway i can do with Storybook - been looking online for a while and i cant find anything that helps.

Comment: Was hoping to get a response haha - i guess it an obscure one

Answer (score 0):

So after a brain slapping day of trying to figure this out i did the following...

In my main webpack config I used SvgStore plugin (spritemap.ts). This configures the nature of how you use the sprite map i.e `reference="icon-logo"` and the output file.

```
module.exports = () => {
  const plugins = [
    //..
    new SvgStore({
      name: 'sprite-store.svg',
      prefix: 'icon-',
    }),
    //...
  ];
  return plugins;
};
```

I then created a new TS file with the svgxhr svg import asynchronous into the project.

Now this was all lovely and working in dev but when we included it into storybook it went t*ts up because it uses it's own webpack config.

Through trail and error i decided to do the following...

in ./storybook/webpack.config.js - I injected the spritemap.ts into the entry files to pull in the generated sprite map into the build so we can still use sprite map referencing

```
config.entry.push(
  path.resolve('./src/spritemap.ts'),
);
```

Inject the svgstore plugin into plugins to generate the spritemap

```
config.plugins.push(new SvgStore({
  name: 'sprite-store.svg',
  prefix: 'icon-',
}));
```

Just thought i would put this there as I couldn't find any answers around.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello John, I have come across the same need to use a svg sprite file in Storybook and finding not much out there on the subject. I came across your post and thought I would ask some questions. What does spritemap.ts do? Does that build the sprite map file and add it too the page?

my email if this format is limiting in response: jason.vanvuren@deluxe.com